# Do I have to use async/await in all methods in call API chain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I was wondering how to implement Dapper Asynchronously. I found [this](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-dapper-asynchronously-in-asp-net-core-2-1/)

Looks cool, but I noticed that there are used async/await in all methods in that call api chain:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("dob/{dateOfBirth}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Employee>>> GetByID(DateTime dateOfBirth)
{
    return await _employeeRepo.GetByDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth);
}
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<List<Employee>> GetByDateOfBirth(DateTime dateOfBirth)
{
    using (IDbConnection conn = Connection)
    {
        string sQuery = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth FROM Employee WHERE DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth";
        conn.Open();
        var result = await conn.QueryAsync<Employee>(sQuery, new { DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth });
        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

So if we would have more layers between, like service etc. then those layers should also have async/await? I think it is redundant and is totally enough to have async/await in place where is method that really returns asynchronous result. In other places like Controller, Services - only Task is required.

Exception can be place where we have using block that would dispose the whole context. So there we have to have async/await also.

Am I right, or I miss something?

---

@EDIT

So controller could be saved as:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("dob/{dateOfBirth}")]
public Task<ActionResult<List<Employee>>> GetByID(DateTime dateOfBirth)
{
    return _employeeRepo.GetByDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth);
}
```

As you see I removed async/await - now only repository has async/await and the result and performance should be the same, right?

Comment: It would really help us if you could show what you propose as an alternative. But yes, you typically end up with an entire call chain that's asynchronous - switching between synchronous and asynchronous "modes" usually ends up being either problematic or inefficient. With a more concrete example, we could give more details.

Comment: @JonSkeet my propose is just remove async/await in other places, like controller, services. Check Edit.

Comment: Right. That's fine if it's *that* simple - and if you're okay with it having slightly different exception semantics. (Suppose `_employeeRepo` is null somehow; in the async/await version, you'll return a faulted task. In your second version, a NullReferenceException would be thrown directly.)

Comment: That's even better :) because usually it means that DI did something wrong.

Comment: @DiPix: Just a David Fowler's 2 cents in his async guidance. https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#prefer-asyncawait-over-directly-returning-task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... - only Task is required.

Yes. But under the condition that you only have one async call and that that is the last statement in your method. The `GetByDateOfBirth()` method does not qualify because of the `ToList()` coming *after* the `await`.

It's called ["eliding the async and await keywords"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) and it is a small optimization.

I usually don't bother to remove them. Having predictable, readable and modification-safe code is more important. Also, `await` helps with converting pesty co- and contra-variant return types.